# KeyDown Delete from ComboBox

Tags: c#

I have a combo box and want to add a key down function so that when <kbd>Delete</kbd> pressed then it will delete the Item in the combo box and sends a null value to the database:

```
    private void comboBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cmbx = (ComboBox)sender;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
        {
            cmbx.SelectedIndex = -1;
            cmbx.SelectedValue = DBNull.Value;
        }
    }
```

But it's not working properly. Any suggestions

Comment: Could you please tag this with the relevant framework you're using?  WPF/Winforms/Whatever?

Comment: What part is not working correctly?  Is the `DBNull.Value` being set properly?  Or are you having trouble sending the value to the database?  If the problem is the latter, we need to see your update code please.

Comment: Please put more effort into your problem description. `But it's not working properly` tells us exactly nothing about what the issue is. Compile time error? Runtime exception? Unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 4):

Your code doesn't really make any sense.

`cmbx.SelectedIndex = -1;` removes the *selection* that from the combo box, it doesn't remove the *selected item*.

Here's a few different methods of removing specific elements of your combobox.

```
// To remove item with index 0:
cmbx.Items.RemoveAt(0);
// To remove currently selected item:
cmbx.Items.Remove(cmbx.SelectedItem);
// To remove "Value1" item:
cmbx.Items.Remove("Value1");
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19fc31ss.aspx

Comment: +1 - Also, I'm hoping the OP doesn't think setting his `SelectedValue = DBNull.Value` actually performs the database transaction.